# Java Card Game Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Output of main shows the following:

Round 1 
Player 0: Queen of Clubs 
Player 1: King of Clubs 
Computer Wins
The War

I want to change the name of Player 1 to Computer but I'm using an array in my 'for' statement. Not sure how to change that so that it just says computer. I think I need to rewrite this sections with player1 and then computer. Can anyone help me with that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Card[][] hands = new Card[2][1];
    Deck myDeck = new Deck();
    int score1;
    int score2;

    score1 = 0;
    score2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        System.out.printf("\nRound %s\n", i);


        for (int player = 0; player < hands.length; player++) {
            hands[player][0] = myDeck.dealCard();

        }

        for (int player = 0; player < hands.length; player++) {
            System.out.printf("Player %d: ", player);
            printHand(hands[player]);


        }
        int player1 = hands[0][0].getValue(); 
        int computer = hands[1][0].getValue();

        if (player1 > computer) {
            System.out.println("Player One Wins The War");
            score1 += 1;

        } else if (computer > player1) {
            System.out.println("Computer Wins The War");
            score2 += 1;

        } else {
            System.out.println("Tie");
        }
```

Comment: Why not give it a try? You might surprise yourself...

Comment: I'd make a `Player` class that holds all things important about a player, i.e.; name, hand, etc. Override the `toString()` method to print that stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about adding a players string array

`String[] playerName = {"Player One", "Computer"};`

Then printing in the for loop with the statement

`System.out.println(playerName[player]);`

Comment: Thanks Kenny - your answer was what I was looking for. Why are so many people on this site so quick to put a post on hold when I did provide details to narrow the answer down.